# Cannot separate DHCPD logs for syslog

Tags: permissions, dhcp, rsyslog

I'm trying to separate DHCPD log from `syslog` file in Ubuntu 16.4 LTS.

In my `dhcpd.conf` file I have added:

```
log-facility local7;
```

And in `rsyslog.conf` file:

```
#Logging for DHCP service
local7 /var/log/dhcp/dhcp.log
```

I have created `dhcp` folder and `dhcp.log` files.

Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: Did you restart both dhcpd and rsyslogd?

Comment: Yes I have restarted rsyslog service and server.

Answer (score 3):

add this on top of the rules-Part in`rsyslog.conf`or if present in`/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

but **DON'T** add `"local7 /var/log/dhcp/dhcp.log"`

```
###############
#### RULES ####
###############

#
# First some standard log files.  Log by facility.
#

if $programname == 'dhcpd' then /var/log/dhcp.log
& stop
```

after that open `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog` and add `/var/log/dhcp.log` like this

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/dhcp.log
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

if you want to rotete daily

or like this

```
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages
/var/log/dhcp.log
{
        rotate 4
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate > /dev/null
        endscript
}
```

if you want to rotate weekly

Comment: I followed your example, but the problem is that it does not stop sending it to syslog. Now it ends up both in the dhcpd log, and in syslog. I thought the `& stop` would take care of the duplication?